# What WiFi router brands or models are considered to be secure?

Tags: wifi, router

I understand that there's no 100% secure firmware. But there are some brands that regularly update their firmware to fix discovered vulnerabilities. What brands of WiFi routers (or specific models) are considered to be secure, stable and provide regular firmware updates? Or maybe even have open-source firmware? I'm looking for a router for home usage, not an enterprise solution.

Comment: How much are you willing to spend and what do you expect beyond "gas wifi" and "is secure"?

Comment: Hopefully up to $100. As for other expectations, I don't need additional features. Mostly stable connection, modern standards support and secure and reliable firmware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cheap solution I use a wifi router well supported by dd-wrt alternative firmware.
[Here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) you can find supported models database.

For more advanced, trouble-safe solution I use Ubiquiti UniFi - the AC-Lite model is really good.